# SQL transaction, insert, then update if the insert is successful

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to do the following:

- table A has only one column consisting of unique numbers (non consecutive)
- table B has two columns, an id (unique non consecutive integers) and a hit_number (positive integers)

Given a number and an id, I'd like to:

Check if the number is present in table A.

- If it is present, then don't do anything, just let me know
- If it's not present, insert it in table A, increment the hit_number column in table B that corresponds to this id and let me know.

It needs to be done in a single transaction, and if two concurrent connections where to be made with the same value, the hit_number should only be increased by one (so I need some isolation I suppose).

I came up with one solution (in this example I'm using sqlite and python) but I'm not sure it's good enough:

something like

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", isolation_level="EXCLUSIVE")
con.execute("create table A (num integer primary key);")
con.execute("create table B (user_id integer primary key, hit_number integer);")

# ... fill it with something

def hit(v, id, con):
    try:
        with con:
           con.execute("INSERT INTO A VALUES (?);" +
                       "UPDATE B SET hit_number=hit_number+1 WHERE user_id=(?);", (v, id))
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
       return False
    return True
```

Would this transaction be atomic? Do I actually need EXCLUSIVE here or will a lower isolation level give the exact same behavior? Is there a better way?

Comment: Smells like denormalized data .. in any case, 1) just use two statements? 2) won't the insert failing prevent the updating from running at all? As for as atomicity, see http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Comment: What if insert successfully and the server crashes and the hit_number is never incremented?

Comment: See the link I posted. Either autocommit is used (and the transaction is commited *only* when the database operations complete) or autocommit is not used and `commit` must be called manually. SQLite is fully ACID. In any case, it still seems "icky".

Comment: This is the ideal use case for a trigger: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only execute *one* statement at a time with the `.execute()` method. Within a transaction, there is never a need to execute two statements in one call like that; the integrity error exception will already raise and abort the transaction:

```
try:
    with con:
       con.execute("INSERT INTO A VALUES (?);", (v,))
       con.execute("UPDATE B SET hit_number=hit_number+1 WHERE user_id=(?);", (id,)
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
   return False
return True
```

Comment: So provided the insert is successful, I'll get an atomic commit right when I exit the "with con:" block. No risk of updating A without updating B right?

Comment: @ArthurB.: Exactly. The `with` block commits *if there was no exception*.

Comment: How about the isolation?

If I run two queries like this in parallel with the same, previously unseen, value v. Can I end up in a state where v is inserted in A but no (or both!) hit_number are updated?

Do I *need* the "EXCLUSIVE" isolation level for this, or will the default isolation level provide the same logic?

Comment: Separate connections do not see other transactions in progress. The default isolation level is just fine.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

If two concurrent transaction are being executed, if the 2nd transaction does not see the other one in progress, what prevents it from thinking inserting the same value is a-ok?

Comment: @ArthurB. Read the link I posted, for starters. It explains (albeit at a lower level) why SQLite is *inherently* ACID. What you are talking about is a Phantom (or perhaps Dirty) Read, and is not possible in a SERIALIZABLE transaction. SQLite default transactions are all SERIALIZABLE. Search - i.e. the SQLite site *and* Wikipedia - for what those terms mean/imply. *Term [re]list*: Transaction, ACID, Serializable, Phantom Read, Dirty Read, Database Isolation Levels.

Comment: I've seen this documentation, I'm asking for a gentler explanation if at all possible. I don't have a very good intuition of the logic and semantic behind SQL isolation levels.

If you can explain what happens with two concurrent requests at the engine level, it would be tremendously helpful. I don't understand how the integrity is maintained short of every transaction creating an exclusive lock on whole database.

Comment: @ArthurB.: The commit for *one* of the transactions would fail since it would violate the integrity. That transaction is then rolled back.

Comment: @ArthurB. See Wikipedia with the terms I suggested for "gentle explanations"; follow the SQLite links for the file lock/WAL approach in SQLite - it is one of the best "gentle" resources I have found on this implementation approach. There are different implementations that can be used - SQLite uses exclusive file locking and/or a WAL. Row-locks (with escalation) and multiversioning (neither of which are supported by SQLite) are also usable strategies.

Comment: Thanks but I've found the Wikipedia pretty dry on the topic :-/